# Use VBA code written for Excel in Access to automatically fill pdf forms

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, pdf-generation

I currently have a macro written in excel so that with the click of a button the highlighted row automatically populates the required excel form fields.  We now need to transfer our database into Microsoft Access so as to aid in readability.  However, we still need to be able to quickly populate our forms from the database.

How can I adapt the code below so that it works in Access?
(the below is just an example)

```
Public Sub Billing_Information()
    Dim sFileHeader As String
    Dim sFileFooter As String
    Dim PDF_FILE As String
    Dim sFileFields As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim lngFileNum As Long
    Dim vClient As Variant

    PDF_FILE = "BI.pdf"


    ' Builds string for contents of FDF file and then writes file to workbook folder.
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    sFileHeader = "%FDF-1.2" & vbCrLf & _
                  "%âãÏÓ" & vbCrLf & _
                  "1 0 obj<</FDF<</F(" & PDF_FILE & ")/Fields 2 0 R>>>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
                  "2 0 obj[" & vbCrLf

    sFileFooter = "]" & vbCrLf & _
                  "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
                  "trailer" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</Root 1 0 R>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "%%EO"


    sFileFields = "<</T(Name)/V(---Name---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Address)/V(---Address---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(City)/V(---City---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Postal Code)/V(---Postal Code---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Unit)/V(---Unit---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Email)/V(---Email---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Phone #)/V(---Phone #---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Claim)/V(---Claim---)>>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<</T(Rate)/V(---Rate---)>>" & vbCrLf

    'Range("A2").Select

    vClient = Range(Selection.Row & ":" & Selection.Row)

    Dim count As Integer
    count = 1

    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Name---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Address---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---City---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Postal Code---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Unit---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Email---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Phone #---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Rate---", vClient(1, count))
    count = count + 1
    sFileFields = Replace(sFileFields, "---Claim---", vClient(1, count))

    sTmp = sFileHeader & sFileFields & sFileFooter


    ' Write FDF file to disk
    sFileName = "BillingMultipule"
    sFileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFileName & ".fdf"
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Output As lngFileNum
    Print #lngFileNum, sTmp
    Close #lngFileNum
    DoEvents

    ' Open FDF file as PDF
    ShellExecute vbNull, "open", sFileName, vbNull, vbNull, SW_NORMAL
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "MakeFDF Error: " + Str(Err.Number) + " " + Err.Description + " " + Err.Source    
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have many different moving parts here. You mention *database* but not yet in Access. You mention *forms* but not Excel userforms. You mention *PDF forms* but use FDF markup, not [Adobe SDK](http://www.khk.net/wordpress/2009/03/04/adobe-acrobat-and-vba-an-introduction/) for interfacing to Adobe objects. Please clearly explain workflow with appropriate terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off, using Forms and Reports in Access, along with built-in "Export" as pdf feature.

You would use the form to select your data, and the report to design the layout of the pdf.

When you export for the first time "manually", it will offer to save the export steps. Click "YES", then use this "Saved Export", in your code, or a macro, to generate the desired pdf output file, when you click your button.

Comment: Would I be able to make that look like the pdf form I had previously?

Comment: Yes, and you'll probably find ways to make it better/easier.

Comment: How can I make it show only one record (i.e one row of the table)?

Comment: On the Property Sheet>Format>Default View. "Single Form" will show one record, "Continuous Form" shows them all. You need to be in design view, to change this.